# Recommended Shake256 digest size for KMAC based HKDF

Tags: sha-3, hkdf, kmac

On the [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HKDF) page for `HKDF`, in the Python Implementation, there is a `hash_length` variable for the `sha256` digest length, used in the `hmac` in the `hmac_sha256` function.

However, if I wanted to replace the `hmac` with a `kmac`, I would have to change the `hmac(...)` into `kmac(...)`, where the underlying hash algorithm is the `shake256` algorithm (`XOF`) - with variable output length.

So my question is what is the recommended length to set the `shake256` digest size to when incorporating it into a `KMAC` based `HKDF`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HKDF already has expansion on top of the MAC that it is based on. What would be the point of using a XOF for that? Why not use the XOF directly or define a different KDF? Because having two different methods for expanding the output seems troublesome to me.

If you're going to use HKDF then use one of the normal SHA-3 / HMAC functions with it. Sure, that's less than optimal, but commonly that's not a huge issue for deriving a limited amount of key material anyway.

Any form of HKDF that redefines the PRF used to derive the key material will not be compatible with anything out there. That's true regardless of the XOF and KMAC standardization.

Comment: Ok thanks - I assume that there isn't a HKDF-like implementation that uses the KMAC algorithm rather than HMAC then?